почему react проект создается с ошибками?
При создании react проекта выдаются такие ошибки
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: test@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) 
dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-17T11_05_11_631Z-eresolve-report.txt

И при импорте компонент, он также выдает ошибку о том, что не может найти файл. Раньше такого не было. Я обновил версию node и npm, но ничего не поменялось.

Создаете через create-react-app? Вышел React 19, не все старые способы создания проекта остались работоспособны. Учитывая, что create-react-app больше не поддерживается, переходите на новые способы если это так. А ошибка говорит, что версии библиотек не совместимы (либо понижать react версию до 18, либо повышать testing-library, если они уже добавили поддержку в версии выше)

все верно, я использую create-react-app, но во всех статьях, которые я читал, проект создается с помощью create-react-app. другого способа я даже не знаю

Сам React 19 вышел совсем недавно 5 декабря, руководства более старые и они работали до этого момента. Сейчас либо через способы, которые описаны в офф. документации с использованием фреймворков (см. NextJS https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project и страницу самого фреймворка как с ним работать), либо через сборщик Vite https://vite.dev/guide/ (он пока еще подтягивает React 18, но обновление до 19 это скорее всего вопрос ближайшего времени).

Ну или как вариант на скорую руку, то в package.json меняйте вручную версии react на старую 18-ю и ставьте её. Может еще версии других библиотек понадобится зафиксировать, раз все равно пока остается шанс, что что-то еще отвалится из библиотек в процессе работы с 19-й версией.

Попробуй установить Yarn в консоли: npm install --global yarn
Затем проект через yarn create react app


Если ранее был установлен React глобально, то нужно сначала удалить глобально, командой npm uninstall -g create-react-app, затем установить глобально npm install -g create-react-app
Попробовать запустить проект, npm start.
Если получим ошибку "Something is already running on port 3000", в папке проекта создадим файл .env, пропишем в нем PORT=4000
Запускаем проект npm start. Проект запуститься с другой ошибкой: Модуль WebVitals не найден.
Устанавливаем npx install web-vitals

Источник

Пожалуй, вы правы. Опишу тут:

Если ранее был установлен React глобально, то нужно сначала удалить глобально командой npm uninstall -g create-react-app, затем установить глобально npm install -g create-react-app
Попробовать запустить проект, npm start.
Если получим ошибку "Something is already running on port 3000", в папке проекта создадим файл .env, пропишем в нем PORT=4000
Запускаем проект npm start. Проект запуститься с другой ошибкой. Модуль WebVitals не найден.
Устанавливаем npx install web-vitals

